# Genesys Conversations Api getConversationsChatMessages(conversationId) is empty

Tags: genesys

I have a node js application where the conversation ID of a web chat is posted. I can see in the console that the conversation ID is generated. But when I run
var currentConversationMessages=conversationsApi.getConversationsChatMessages(conversationId);
The currentConversationMessages is empty even though I can see text being posted in the chat.

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKqVM.png)

Comment: How do you know the conversationId?